# Separate class for list of objects?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class in Active Record pattern. Lets call it "Car". So I have all my methods like insert, update etc but they work only on single object. What if I want to work on a list of these objects? Should I create a separate class lets say "CarCollection" that will be used to work on list of Car objects? Or should I create a method in my Car class that will return a list of Car object? I am a beginner in OOP but the second option (method that returns a list) seems kinda wrong.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say yourself: you'll have to work with a collection of cars. The question is in what class you're going to store this list.

When you're just using it as a standalone example you can store the collection in the class that holds your `main` method. In reality though you'll probably have a class `Dealership` or something similar that logically contains a list of cars.

There are other posibilities like classes specific for performing actions on a list of objects like a `CarManager`, but they are to be used with caution.

Comment: I generally find it a good idea to make a class to represent a collection.  If you have a collection of objects in your code and you are not manipulating it, why do you have it?  If you are manipulating it, where do you put the code to manipulate the collection--inline?  if you put it inline, how do you not duplicate it?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the idea of a `CarManager` (aka: a class that holds a collection of items and performs actions on them)? This is the approach I prefer as well, it separates the actions on the cars nicely from the object that actually holds the cars. I realize I haven't made this very clear in my post.

Comment: Yes I was, and sorry if it didn't look like it but I was agreeing with you and voting it up--just thought it was worth a comment with a little more reasoning because I consider it pretty important.

Comment: What if I just use the CarCollection class to store a collection so I can fill a dropdown menu later. Should I stick with separate class to do so?

Comment: That's the same concept as a `CarManager`, but with a different classname. Yes, this is a perfectly valid approach. You might want to reconsider the naming though: I myself prefer to use `CarManager`, `CarHandler`, etc.

Comment: Manager or Handler implies doing many different things with the Cars.  Such an example would be creating a car manager where you can add, edit, delete, update cars etc.  It also implies there maybe business logic embedded as to what cars can be updated, what color they can be, etc.  However a CarCollection implies just that - a base collection of cars.  I normally use this when I have base logic for my collection classes to perform similar operations.  So my vote is CarCollection for basic collection, CarManager for a more complex set of operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not a huge fan of the active record pattern, but if you're going this route, I'd expect the methods that return multiple cars would still live in your `Car` class - you wouldn't use a separate class.

That seems to be the way [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) does it.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard practice to use Arrays, List or Dictionary. I like using Dictionaries because it is VERY quicker to link classes together with unique entries.

Create a class (Not a struct) called car.

You can use it in a Dictionary to enable Primary Unique key acceleration.

```
Public class Car
{
 public string id;
 public string name;
}
```

Create:

```
Dictionary<string, Car> carList = new Dictionary<string, Car>();
```

You can add this inside your method and pass it as parameters or create it global (according to your application)

To add:

```
Car car = new Car(){id = "1", Name="car1"};
carList[car.id] = car;
```

You can use Linq to link your classes together (almost like SQL):
[Basic LINQ Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397927.aspx)